# Can anyone explain to me, how magento cron_schedule exactly runs?

Tags: magento-1.4

When we run cron.php of magento then some jobs created in cron_schedule table of magento ? Can anyone let me know how magento execute these jobs exactly ? I mean how job status is changed from pending to success.  Cron.php only insert jobs in the table not execute jobs

Answer (score 16):

You'd want to read through the following article available directly from the MagentoCommerce website which covers all that you need to know about cron functionality & Magento:

[Magento - Wiki - How to Set Up a Cron Job](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job)

**To highlight: Inner workings**

Magento crontab mechanism is triggered periodically using system cron job.
The call is initiated in cron.php file:

```
<?php
// initialize configuration and load event observers only from /crontab/ section
Mage::getConfig()->init()->loadEventObservers('crontab');
 
// initialize crontab event area
Mage::app()->addEventArea('crontab');
 
// dispatch 'default' event for observers specified in crontab configuration
Mage::dispatchEvent('default');
```

This sequence will invoke `Mage_Cron_Model_Observer→dispatch()`, which in turn will:

- execute scheduled tasks
- generate future scheduled tasks if needed
- clean up history of scheduled tasks

Tasks are scheduled for each time the job needs to be run based on

```
<schedule><cron_expr>0 1 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
```

expression and stored in cron_schedule table. Each record consists of the following fields:

- `schedule_id` - unique identifier for scheduled task
- `job_code` - job identifier from configuration
- `status` - can be one of `pending, running, success, missed, error`
- `messages` - custom text reported by method that was executed by the job
- `created_at` - date/time when the task was created at
- `scheduled_at` - date/time when the task is planned to be executed
- `executed_at` - date/time when the task was actually executed (null prior to execution)
- `finished_at` - date/time when the task finished execution (null prior to execution)

  When schedules are generated, `status` is set to `pending`, `created_at` to `now()` and `scheduled_at` to target date/time.

When pending schedules are executed, `status` is set to `running` and `executed_at` to `now()`.

When scheduled task is finished successfully, `status` is set to `success` and `finished_at` to `now()`.

When scheduled task has thrown an exception, `status` is set to error and `finished_at` to `now()`.

If task status is `pending` and `scheduled_at` is older than “Missed if not run within” configured value, status is set to `missed`.

Comment: Hurry for the documentation which Magento preserved...

Comment: @janw pardon me?

Comment: The link above is broken (general redirect). I hate how Magento broke all those links.

Comment: Yeah, it is upsetting, the same with their forum information too. Anyway, I did copy most of the article into my answer so it's still relatively complete :)