# Cron_schedule table - job status = gone

Tags: database, cron

I'm inspecting the cron_schedule table and do see a few jobs with the status "gone":

```
mysql> select job_code,status,messages,created_at,scheduled_at,executed_at,finished_at from cron_schedule where job_code like "klevu%";
+---------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| job_code                  | status  | messages                                                          | created_at          | scheduled_at        | executed_at         | finished_at         |
+---------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| klevu_search_product_sync | gone    | Process "20363" on host "www.example.com" cannot be found anymore | 2016-06-21 07:42:00 | 2016-06-21 08:00:00 | 2016-06-21 08:00:07 | 2016-06-21 08:00:07 |
+---------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

According [this post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/18497/6291) the status "gone" doesn't exist actually. Any ideas what might causing the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento does not have this type of Cronjob status for a process.

**Generally,it have 5 statuses:**

- pending
- running
- success
- missed
- error

For the status `gone`,*May be any custom extension is responsible*.As per as your question,you have used **3rd party  extension** `klevu_search` which may  be responsible for that.So check this extension and fix the issue.